# Building a second javascript file with Yeoman

Tags: javascript, yeoman, gruntjs

I'm trying to use yeoman in my project, and I'm facing an issue while trying to build it with Grunt:

I have an application.js which is the main file used by the application, using require.js. After running Grunt build, the js file is created in the dist folder, concatenated and minified.

The problem is when I try to create a second javascript file (e.g. application2.js) to be used in another page in the application. After running Grunt the file is created but is empty. I tried using the same js as in the one working to rule out some js or require.js problem, but is the same.

Only thing I can figure is that somewhere in Grunt is configured to process only that file, and actually when running I can see in the console the following:

```
Found a block:
    <!-- build:js scripts/application.js -->
    <script data-main="scripts/application" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
Updating config with the following assets:
    - dist/scripts/application.js

Found a block:
    <!-- build:js scripts/application2.js -->
    <script data-main="scripts/application2" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
Updating config with the following assets:
    - dist/scripts/application2.js

Configuration is now:

  cssmin:
  { dist: {} }

  concat:
  { 'dist/scripts/application.js': [ 'dist/scripts/application.js' ],
  'dist/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js': [ 'app/components/modernizr/modernizr.js' ],
  'dist/scripts/application2.js': [ 'dist/scripts/application2.js' ] }

  uglify:
  { 'dist/scripts/application.js': 'dist/scripts/application.js',
  'dist/components/requirejs/require.js': 'app/components/requirejs/require.js',
  'dist/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js': 'dist/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
  'dist/scripts/application2.js': 'dist/scripts/application2.js' }

  requirejs:
  { dist:
   { options:
      { baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
        optimize: 'none',
        preserveLicenseComments: false,
        useStrict: true,
        wrap: true,
        uglify2: {},
        name: 'application',
        out: 'dist/scripts/application.js',
        mainConfigFile: 'app/scripts/application.js' } } }

Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
>> RequireJS optimizer finished
Uncompressed size: 1361156 bytes.
Compressed size: 304370 bytes gzipped.
```

Concat and Uglify tasks refer to the second javascript file, but requirejs. I tried changing the property "mainConfigFile", to include both, but it keeps getting overriden...

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm first curious why you are trying to define multiple application files within your yeoman system? This is for multiple HTML pages, I'm guessing? Or do you have two:

```
<script data-main="..." src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

within a single HTML file?

As far as the fix for this: mainConfigFile is generated using the 'out' parameter, so setting it won't work here.

Your requirejs section needs a 'dist' section for each file. They also need name and out specified manually. Not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior.

```
requirejs: {
   dist1: {
      options: {
         name: 'application', out: 'dist/scripts/application.js',
         ...}
   },
   dist2: {
      options: {
         name: 'application2', out: 'dist/scripts/application2.js',
         ...
```

You also need to add the two separate HTML files to useminPrepare, but it looks like you have already done that OR you are referencing application and application2 within one HTML file (not sure what the consequences of two requirejs configs in one html file would be).

```
    useminPrepare: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html','<%= yeoman.app %>/index2.html'],
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    },
```

For posterity, I also added the two scripts to bower config, but I can't be 100% sure it even matters:

```
    bower: {
        all: {
            rjsConfig: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/application.js','<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/application2.js']
        }
    }
```

Here is my resulting config output: http://pastie.org/7321492

Comment: That worked like a charm! I was confused because didn`t see anywhere that yeoman was so focused into single page apps. I was not even aware that the first js "application.js" was being defined in Grunt by Yeoman, because by chance I also called my main js file "application.js"

Comment: I was also quite surprised, that yeoman's primary use is building one-page apps. But your solution has worked perfectly.